# MaxDB - User does not access tables

Tags: sql, oracle, permissions, maxdb

I have created a new user in a MaxDb database. I assign a role that has access to all the tables in roleprivileges but the user can not see these tables.

The user can access the tables if I assign permissions directly to the tables in tableprivileges.

The role has access, other users have this role assigned and they see all the tables.

What can be failing?

Answer (score 2):

Today I've heard of MaxDB for the first time (what an ignoramus, eh?). I'm not sure why you tagged your question with the "Oracle" tag; Google says that MaxDB <> Oracle.

Anyway: it sounds like *common* problems in Oracle's PL/SQL, where privileges - acquired via roles - won't work, but have to be granted directly to the user.

Saying that "other users have this role assigned and they see all the tables", are you sure that they don't have direct privileges granted as well?

Comment: Apparently, there seems to be no tags available in S.O  for `MaxDB` !

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this deals indeed with MaxDB, and not with Oracle:
In contrast to privileges, roles need to be activated for a user session. Assigning is not enough. It is done by command `SET ROLE <role>`.
A role may also be activated as default for every new session, with command:
`ALTER USER <user> DEFAULT ROLE <role>`. 
You can also activate all roles assigned to the user, like this:
 `ALTER USER <user> DEFAULT ROLE ALL`.